# Windows 8 share on facebook and get response

Tags: facebook, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to impletent share mechanism in windows phone 8.1 app.
I want to be able to share some app content and react to it in the application meaning,

1. Click to share
2. Pick medium
3. If picked == facebook and shared -> do something
4. if picked == somethingelse and shared -> do something
   etc..

So far i managed to make the

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        this._navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView().DataRequested += OnDataRequested;
        DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView().TargetApplicationChosen += SenderOnTargetApplicationChosen;
    }



private async void OnDataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs args)
        {
            _facebookPicked = false;
            var request = args.Request;
            var shareDescription = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView().GetString("ShareDescription");
            var deferral = args.Request.GetDeferral();

            request.Data.Properties.Title = "Some title";
            request.Data.Properties.Description = "sometext";

            deferral.Complete();
    }


 private void SenderOnTargetApplicationChosen(DataTransferManager sender, TargetApplicationChosenEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.ApplicationName == "Facebook")
            {
                _facebookPicked = true;
            }

        }
```

What i cannot figure out how to do is determined if some one actually pressed the share button upon picking the target app. Is there any event i can intercept?

Comment: You mean, know if someone actually pressed Share in Facebook app? You can't do that.

Comment: Is there any other way i can accomplish such a thing? Any facebook sdk's i can use? I tried to use official facebook sdk but i have tons of problems while using it with windows phone 8.1

Comment: You could do the whole sharing yourself inside your app using the Facebook C# SDK, but that requires more work and is probably overkill for simple sharing scenarios.